# Writing BigIntegers from different classes to a file

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I am trying to write to a text file with data from different classes but can't seem to get it working. I have looked at different questions but not one that solves my issue. One error that comes up is that my keyboard scanner says is never closed and I don't know how to fix this and then the main issue is that my code doesn't work when trying to save to a file:

Comment: Please edit and construct a [mcve], and describe the error you're having.

Comment: I suspect your problem is you're trying to access `RSA.keyboard...` but you can't just get at the variable like that. You might be better off just creating a new `Scanner` instance in `FileWrite`, or else instantiate `FileWrite` and pass whatever value you need from `RSA`.

Comment: I have done that change and created a new scanner in the FileWrite class but it still doesn't create a text file with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system may be writing to the file, but you haven't specified where `encryption.txt` is, so it might be in a folder somewhere.

Either way, you should probably use `try-with-resources` and also fully specify the file location. For example:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
BigInteger e = BigInteger.valueOf(761);
BigInteger m = keyboard.nextBigInteger();
keyboard.nextLine();

try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("\\\\share\\path\\to\\folder\\encyrption.txt", "UTF-8")) {
    writer.println("Message: " + m);
    writer.println("BigInteger: " + e);
}
```

Note: you may need to catch/throw `FileNotFoundException` and `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Comment: AFAIR directly writing to an unmapped Windows share from within Java is not possible. Only network shares mapped to a drive letter are accessible through the drive letter.

Comment: @Robert - I had tested this and it worked (with a path to a share which I had separately mapped to a letter). I just re-tested it there and it worked going to a share that I don't have mapped :)

Comment: @notyou i have made these changes but its saying that 'keyboard' is never closed?

Comment: @Bretty135 you *could* close the `Scanner` (`keyboard.close()`) but be warned that this will also close `System.in`, which may not be what you want. Did you try the snippet I wrote above - it works just fine for me.